# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied (after multiple successful writting attemps in the file)

Tags: python, python-3.x, permissions

I wrote a code which query a mongo database and write results in a file. 
My code create the file and start to write in it **succesfully**. But after multiple iterations (not sure if the number of iteration is fix or not) I got a **PermissionError**.

I've search about it but I only found answers about people who got the error at first attempt because they don't have permission. I will precise that I am not doing anything on my computer during the execution so I really don't understand how it can happen.

**Here is parts of the code:**

```py
def query(self, query_date_part, query_actKey_part, filepath):
    empty = True
    print("0.0 %")
    for i in range(len(query_date_part)):
        query = {"dt": query_date_part[i], "actKey": query_actKey_part}
        cursor = self.collection.find(query)
        while cursor.alive:
            try:
                if empty:
                    with open(filepath, 'w') as fp:
                        json.dump(cursor.next(), fp, default=json_util.default)
                        empty = False
                else:
                    append_to_json(filepath, cursor.next())
            except StopIteration:
                print("Stop Iteration")
        print(str(round(float(i+1) / len(query_date_part) * 100, ndigits=2)) + " %")
    return 0
```

```py
def append_to_json(filepath, data):
    """
    Append data in JSON format to the end of a JSON file.
    NOTE: Assumes file contains a JSON object (like a Python dict) ending in '}'.
    :param filepath: path to file
    :param data: dict to append
    """
    # construct JSON fragment as new file ending
    new_ending = ", " + json.dumps(data, default=json_util.default)[1:-1] + "}\n"
    # edit the file in situ - first open it in read/write mode
    with open(filepath, 'r+') as f:
        f.seek(0, 2)        # move to end of file
        index = f.tell()    # find index of last byte
        # walking back from the end of file, find the index
        # of the original JSON's closing '}'
        while not f.read().startswith('}'):
            index -= 1
            if index == 0:
                raise ValueError("can't find JSON object in {!r}".format(filepath))
            f.seek(index)
        # starting at the original ending } position, write out
        # the new ending
        f.seek(index)
        f.write(new_ending)`
```

**Part of the output:**

```
6.75 %
Stop Iteration
6.76 %
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/mongodbtk/mquerytk.py", line 237, in <module>
        mdbc.query(split_date(2017,5,6,1,0,2017,5,16,10,0,step=2), {"$in": ["aFeature"]}, 'test.json')
    File "C:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/mongodbtk/mquerytk.py", line 141, in query
        append_to_json(filepath, cursor.next())
    File "C:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/mongodbtk/mquerytk.py", line 212, in append_to_json
        with open(filepath, 'r+') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test.json'
Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Note:** The size of the file increase during the execution. When it crash it is about 300 Mo, I still have a lot of space on my hard drive but maybe the size of the file can be an issue ?

**Config:** I use Windows 7, Python 3.6 and my IDE is PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2

Comment: using "with open..." should close the file.  is it possible that it's not?

Comment: Are you sure `append_to_json` is executing multiple time?seems it is in `else` condition

Comment: @itzMEonTV The if else is just to recreate the file at first iteration then append_to_json is executed multiple time (I am sure since the size of the file increase during execution)

Comment: Please revise your question to describe which operating system you are running on; the way Windows and Linux handle concurrent accesses to files is different.  If you are on Windows, my strong guess is there is a code path under which you have the file open twice at the same time

Comment: @SamHartman My configuration is already at the end of my question and indeed I am using Windows. Can you precise your guess ?

Comment: In windows, by default when a process opens a file it opens it exclusively--no one else can open that file.  So only one open of a given file.  The symptom you're seeing suggests that lock has not been cleared by the file being closed.  So I'd look at your code for things that could cause that.

Comment: @SamHartman My first thought was also this one but what makes me confuse is that the loop iterate more than 100 times before raising this error so I can't figure out why if previous iterations are fine why soudainly Permission is denied

Comment: @Gabriel welcome to the wonderful world of race conditions.

Comment: Guess: the file  became too big and the locks are not releases sufficiently quick because it needs  time to flush the buffers. See possible help: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_fsync.htm

Comment: @valentin Definitly possible. I will read that and see if it fix the problem

Comment: @valentin I am currently testing this idea. It looks like it slow down the execution a lot (really a lot). Full execution will take hours so I will give you the result later. Since I am not 100% sure that I use this well can you suggest me an implementation as an answer so I can validate it as solution of my problem if it's successful ?

Comment: @valentin It still raise PermissionError. Maybe my use of fsync is not right

Comment: Change the design. In `query`,  instead of opening and closing the file for every element in cursor,  open the file first and then start to add elements from the cursor.  Or, if memory permits, build the entire json in memory and write to file  at the end.

Comment: @valentin build the entire json in meomry is impossible, way to huge. I can try to open and close for each query instead of each element but I did that because I have memory probelms. But I will try it with small query and see if it's better

Comment: Reducing frequence and number of open seems to give some improvment. Since it will take few hours to finish executing I will give you some news tomorrow but it seems to work. At least I hope ^^

Comment: Doing one open per query instead of one for each element seems to solve the problem. Thank for your help and I will keep digging to try to understand exactly what was the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, and after testing it out, it seems like there might be some "bug" when trying to write to the same file too "often", multiple times in each sec. I'll provide a very small code snippet what you can test with:

```
import csv

text = "dfkjghdfkljghflkjghjkdfdfgsktjgrhsleiuthsl uirghuircbl iawehcg uygbc sgygerh"
FIELD_NAMES = ['asd', 'qwe']


with open('test.txt', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=FIELD_NAMES)
    writer.writeheader()

max = 10000
i = 0

while i <= max:
    print(str(i))
    with open('test.txt', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=FIELD_NAMES)
        rowData = {'asd': text, 'qwe': text}
        writer.writerow(rowData)
    i += 1
```

The code I think is pretty self explanatory. I got the error very randomly, sometimes it happens after the ~75th iteration, sometimes it can get to even ~750, but it looks like the code can't reach the limit. So I recommend you to try to write more data a few times rather than few data very often. I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what happen and I solved the problem by writting more data each time to open and close the file less often. However, I still havn't find a 100% sure explanation of why it happens :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
except StopIteration:
    if not fp.closed: fp.close()
    print("Stop Iteration")
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand well what you want to do with this code. I post a lot of code not well commented so maybe this is not what you mean ?

Comment: No it's not working. And by the way I don't really understand why you write this in the except StopIteration. Because this except will not happen often and even if it's call StopIteration it have nothing to do with my issue. So I may not have understand your idea or you get confuse by my not proper code

Comment: Ok. Is this happening just after stopiteration comes? From error log it is like that. Is it same all the time? Also what I am trying is to debug your code only. There will be cases like max open file limit for particular user, or like `close` not working as expected as consistent.

Comment: No it's not link with stop iteration, I should have post more logs and no it's not always same exact time. 
Yes my code do thousands of open/close so I am currently following the suggestion of valentin to reduce the frequence and number of open/close of the file

Comment: I have one doubt. if `cursor.next()` raise `StopIteration` error, means cursor is empty now. So why you are not `break` in `except` ?

Comment: The code do multiple queries and sometimes some of them return empty results (so it raise the error) but I still want to do next queries so I just log it and continue

Comment: Well I am not 100% sure of the origine of the empty cursor but that was my conclusion and anyway I want to continue to do next queries

Comment: By the way reducing the number and frequence of open seems to have an effect for the first time I reach 17% and it is still going without raising PermissionError

Comment: try something like keeping 1000 (you can change it) objects and do writes.So it will performing well anyways other than open in every loop.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a Race Condition. Creating a helper function which does same task as a function raising a race condition, worked out for me.
For example, if a code block or function A() is creating a race condition, then we can handle this exception by calling again another helper function A_helper() which also does the same thing.
A python code example:

```
try:
   A()
except PermissionError:
   # Do something
else:
   A_helper()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving permission using

```
chmod 755 file.extension
```

See: [*Permission Eerrno13*](https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied/)

Answer (score -1):

Your file is located somewhere where your program can't access it. Try moving it to a different directory. Or it might be you are entering the wrong filepath. I hope this Works for you!

Comment: The file is created by this program and it already writes many times in it before raising this error

Comment: Is there any function in the computer which doesn't permit python to access files that are to big?